# Using int containers with two x MCP3008 ADC Rpi

Tags: python, int, containers, analog-digital-converter

The following code uses 2 MCP3008 chips attached to Rpi and  my home alarm panel. These 16 analog values fluctuate between 600 and 715 out of 1023 depending on PIRs etc.

The Int value prints out:

```
  Chip A - 1023       Chip B -  242
  Chip A - 1023       Chip B - 1023
  Chip A -    0       Chip B -   68
  Chip A - 1023       Chip B -  599
  Chip A - 1023       Chip B - 1023
  Chip A -   16       Chip B - 1023
  Chip A - 1023       Chip B - 1023
  Chip A - 1023       Chip B - 1023
```

I need:

```
Value 1 = chip 1 readvalue 1
Value 2 = chip 1 readvalue 2 
etc...
```

I tried strings, lists, IO, wrappers but I only get the first value.

Could you please go into more detail about what you want? Currently, it is unclear. –  Sildoreth 35 mins ago

MCP3008_A and MCP3008_B print out the analog values from the chip.I want to assign each of those values to a specific name, eg.Value1 = 1023, Value2 = 654 etc.. Ultimately I want to be able to write that ( if Value 2 >=653 ) and (Value10 <= 702) do something. hope this explains it a bit better –  maurice1 19 mins ago

Maybe to be clearer, At the bottom of the code I have #V1 = input.readline() , #V2= etc. I need to know what I should put in thereto read the output from MCP3008_A –  maurice1 1 min ago   edit

Could you please add all this information to the original post? –  Sildoreth 38 secs ago

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
#  https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit-Raspberry-Pi-Python-Code/blob/master/Adafruit_MCP3008/mcp3008.py
# just some bitbang code for testing all 8 channels

import RPi.GPIO as GPIO, time, os
import time      # import time for the sleep function
import os
import sys
import cStringIO
from cStringIO import StringIO
import io
DEBUG = 1
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)

# read SPI data from MCP3008 chip, 8 possible adc's (0 thru 7)
def readadc(adcnum, clockpin, mosipin, misopin, cspin):
    if ((adcnum > 16) or (adcnum < 0)):
        return -1
    GPIO.output(cspin, True)

    GPIO.output(clockpin, False)  # start clock low
    GPIO.output(cspin, False)     # bring CS low

    commandout = adcnum
    commandout |= 0x18  # start bit + single-ended bit
    commandout <<= 3    # we only need to send 5 bits here
    for i in range(5):
        if (commandout & 0x80):
            GPIO.output(mosipin, True)
        else:
            GPIO.output(mosipin, False)
                commandout <<= 1
                GPIO.output(clockpin, True)
                GPIO.output(clockpin, False)

    adcout = 0
    # read in one empty bit, one null bit and 10 ADC bits
    for i in range(12):
        GPIO.output(clockpin, True)
        GPIO.output(clockpin, False)
        adcout <<= 1
        if (GPIO.input(misopin)):
            adcout |= 0x1

    GPIO.output(cspin, True)

    adcout /= 2       # first bit is 'null' so drop it
    return adcout



if __name__=='__main__':
    try:
        # change these as desired
        SPICLK = 11     #MCP3008_13
        SPIMISO = 9     #MCP3008_12
        SPIMOSI = 10    #MCP3008_11
        SPICS = 8       #MCP3008_10
        SPICLK2 = 17    #MCP3008_13
        SPIMISO2 = 27   #MCP3008_12
        SPIMOSI2 = 22   #MCP3008_11
        SPICS2 = 7      #MCP3008_10
        # set up the SPI interface pins 
        GPIO.setup(SPICLK, GPIO.OUT)
        GPIO.setup(SPIMISO, GPIO.IN)
        GPIO.setup(SPIMOSI, GPIO.OUT)
        GPIO.setup(SPICS, GPIO.OUT)
        GPIO.setup(SPICLK2, GPIO.OUT)
        GPIO.setup(SPIMISO2, GPIO.IN)
        GPIO.setup(SPIMOSI2, GPIO.OUT)
        GPIO.setup(SPICS2, GPIO.OUT)

        while True:
            #print "",
            time.sleep(1)
            for adcnum in range(8):
                MCP3008_A = readadc(adcnum, SPICLK, SPIMOSI, SPIMISO, SPICS)
                MCP3008_B = readadc(adcnum, SPICLK2, SPIMOSI2, SPIMISO2, SPICS2)

                print '  Chip A - ' "%4d" % MCP3008_A,
                print '      Chip B - ' "%4d" % MCP3008_B,
                print ''
                time.sleep(0.3) 
                d1=str(MCP3008_A)
                d2=str(MCP3008_B)
            print "--------------------------------------"

                #V1 = input.readline()
                #V2 = input.readline(2)
                #V3 = input.readline()
                #v4 = input.read()



    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        pass

    GPIO.cleanup()
```

Comment: Could you please go into more detail about what you want?  Currently, it is unclear.

Comment: MCP3008_A and MCP3008_B print out the analog values from the chip.I want to assign each of those values to a specific name,  eg.Value1 = 1023, Value2 = 654 etc..   Ultimately I want to be able to write that ( if Value 2 >=653 ) and (Value10 <= 702) do something. hope this explains it a bit better

Comment: Maybe to be clearer,   At the bottom of the code I have      #V1 = input.readline() , #V2=  etc. I need to know what I should put in thereto read the output from MCP3008_A

Comment: Could you please add all this information to the original post?